# Check if item is in infinite List

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a fairly basic question, about comparing with infinite lists. The problem is similar to this:

```
25 `elem` [x^2 | x <- [1..]]
```

obviously this is `true`.
However, how do I deal with values that are not int the list, like

```
26 `elem` [x^2 | x <- [1..]]
```

Because it's an infinite list, Haskell doesn't have an answer for this, although it seems kinda obvious, that once we are past 6^2 we can't reach 26 anymore, so I want to stop there.

Now I could limit the x like:

```
[x^2 | x <- [1..6]]
```

Easy.

But what I do in examples like that:

```
[prod | k <- [1..], let prod = product [1..k]]
```

and I want to check if my number is in that list? Or what is an alternative way to get the result of this calculation?

Comment: Do you know that your list will always be in increasing order?

Comment: In general you can not know if a list is infinite, since that would sove the *Halting problem*. In this case however you can know this, since the list strictuly increases.

Comment: Furthermore `[prod | k <- [1..], let prod = product [1..k]]` is equivalent to `[product [1..k] | k <- [1..]]`

Comment: … is equivalent to `scanl1 (*) [1..]`!

Comment: Yes, the list will always be in increasing order. And the actual computation is more complex (multiplying primes).

Comment: you could use `dropWhile (< n)` and then inspect the resulting list to see whether it contains `n`. I think the answer you're looking for should mention that this is precisely what laziness is good for: you don't have to decide to limit the list when you're constructing it, instead you can compose useful functions in the most natural way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your list is in increasing order, you can [find](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:find) an element that’s at least what you’re looking for and check separately whether it’s the same:

```
> let elemIncreasing x l = find (>= x) l == Just x
> let factorials = scanl1 (*) [1..]
> 120 `elemIncreasing` factorials
True
> 121 `elemIncreasing` factorials
False
```

Answer (score 8):

The [data-ordlist](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html) package has many utility functions for dealing with sorted lists, including `member`:

```
Data.List.Ordered> 25 `member` [n^2 | n <- [1..]]
True
Data.List.Ordered> 26 `member` [n^2 | n <- [1..]]
False
Data.List.Ordered> 24 `member` [product [1..k] | k <- [1..]]
True
Data.List.Ordered> 25 `member` [product [1..k] | k <- [1..]]
False
```

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that we have some order < and we know that for the lists we are interested in we have a

```
sortedElem _ _ [] = False
sortedElem (<) y (x:xs) | y == x = True
                        | x < y  = False
                        | True   = sortedElem (<) y xs
```

And you could define special cases e.g.

```
elemIncreasing = sortedElem (<)
elemDecreasing = sortedElem (>)
```

I’m on my phone so I’ve not tested this. It should work in principle but the compiler may have a few issues. I’m sure they can be fixed.

Comment: I wouldn't use `(<)` in your type signature, since it doesn't seem to ***do*** anything other than indicate if the haystack is ascending or descending. Consider instead `data ListOrder = Asc | Desc` and `sortedElem :: (Eq a, Ord a) => ListOrder -> a -> [a]`

Comment: This implementation does not require that the elements implement `Ord` or indeed that they are sorted by this ordering. The two examples work for lists of things that do implement `Ord` but the `sortedElem` function could be used for e.g. lists of complex numbers sorted by e.g. increasing magnitude, or lists of numbers sorted by their largest factor or any other bizarre ordering.

Comment: Are you sure? If that's the case, I'm not sure how, since you use as a guard `x < y` which operates on `Ord a`.

Comment: and of course if your list isn't sorted, this is actually an impossible task.

Comment: @AdamSmith That does not require `Ord` since `<` is the name of the argument, shadowing the one in the `Ord` type class.

Comment: `<` operates on whatever you pass it. It is lexically bound as a function parameter. The following are equivalent: `satisfies (<) a b = a < b` and `satisfies f a b = f a b`

Comment: @chi ah ha, interesting! I hadn't thought of using an infix variable name inside a pattern match. I don't particularly like it here (shadowing seems unnecessarily complex, subjectively!) but it's good to know!

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes, it is tricky. Personally, I always avoid it, if only to avoid the warning.

Comment: @AdamSmith I don't think "if your list isn't sorted, this is actually an impossible task" is so obvious as you claim. I bet I can invent other properties of a list than sortedness that would let me check whether an element is in it or not. As a trivial example: lists that are either sorted or have the first two elements switched. As a more complicated example: lists that are the flattening of an infinite [search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree#Binary_Search_Tree).

Comment: @DanielWagner true, I misspoke. I should have written "If your list is in arbitrary order, this is actually an impossible take."

Comment: This is just the distinction between recursive and r.e. Sets